# Conditional overwrites variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This jQuery structure stores selected value from an option list on `selectedCourse` variable, and a conditional checks if is different to 0. In that case it sends trought ajax `selectedCourse` value to a separate php file.

Problem: Before the conditional, variable stores selected numerical value. After it, it is overwriten with TRUE. In this case you can see ir clearly: first alert shows the numerical value selected, and second one shows TRUE.

Why is this conditional changing `selectedCourse` value? Shouldn't it just check if the condition is happening or not? Thank you.

```
$('#class_conf').on('change', '#cl_course', 'select', function () {
    var selectedCourse = $('#class_conf').find('#cl_course').val();
    alert(selectedCourse);
    if(selectedCourse = !0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'config/forms/class_conf/class_form_subjects.php',
            data: {
                co_rel_co: selectedCourse
            }
        }).done(function (datos) {
            $('#cl_subject').prepend(datos);
        });
    }
    alert(selectedCourse);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Condition should be `selectedCourse != 0` instead of `selectedCourse = !0`

The value of `!0` is **true** and you are assigning it to `selectedCourse`

Comment: very grateful. I'll tick in 8 minutes.